# What is a good merge strategy for branches off branches?

Tags: git, merge

This scenario comes up every so often, I have a `feature` branch that has done some work and filed a  PR. While waiting for approval I started working on the next task, `enhancement` which happens to be dependent on the previous work that is under review and not yet merged to `master`. So for the `enhancement` branch, I branch off `feature` and create another PR.

It looks something like this:
[image: git branch image]

My question is what is the best/good merge workflow assuming I don't know which order the PRs will be approved in? Should I merge `feature` into `master` and then rebase/merge `master` into `enhancement` or merge `enhancement` into `feature` and then `feature` into `master`? I would think from a code base perspective it is the same but maybe conflicts, history, or something else would be easier with one vs the other. Finally, I need to get passing test runs before merging, I'm not sure which method would require new test runs or not (assume that if I change the code on the branch I need a new test).

Comment: You should ask whoever is in charge of merging the feature branch into the master branch. Those people should have a plan for the situation that you are in now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common to have `feature` branches that are continually being worked on and either fully merged or cherry-picked into the `master` branch. So the latter of your answers would strike me as most typical: merge `enhancement` into `feature` and then `feature` into `master`.